# Tree and total probability rule (two events)

Tags: probability, trees, set-partition

I'd like to know if the tree related to the following rule:
[image]

is the first or the second one or can be both depends on the context. If possible, make some example.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the second tree is enough to heuristically illustrate the rule, but may lead the reader into thinking B occurs with probability 1.  The first tree is more complete since it is exhaustive: it shows all possible states of the world.

Comment: Hello @Golden_Ration thank you very much for your answer.